# Table cell spacing broken by white-space: nowrap

Tags: html, css

I have a table where each cell contains a text input. Next to the text input I have a span. I'd like this span to sit over the text input right hand side as a label.

The HTML structure for each cell is simply:

```
<td>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
        <span>A</span>
     </div>
</td>
```

If I leave no white space between the input and span, it actually works how I'd like, but I'd rather not have to make a massive long line in my HTML (table 3 in the jsfiddle).

I added a line break, which obviously went badly (table 2) as the span then goes onto the next line.

I figured I could fix this by applying nowrap to the div, but that also went badly (table 1) as for some reason I don't understand the table cell sizes are no longer correct.

My questions are: why is this happening, and what would be the best way to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/e01azjoc/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/77v9hjhr/ or https://jsfiddle.net/pqx1nzm3/
"slow" comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who told you to put `margin-left: -1;` to your `span` in order to fix anything?
Position `absolute` should be used for your SPAN inside a position `relative` parent `div`

Now this example works the same for every cell ***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e01azjoc/1/)***

```
.inputCell {         /* The DIV inside your TD */
    position:relative;
}

.cellLabel {        /* The SPAN to overlay INPUT */
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    right:3px;
}
```

Also, since I suppose one should be able to enter some text inside those inputs, you clearly don't want the SPAN's `"A"` to overlay any input's text.  In that case add some right padding to the input - it will allow you that the SPAN's text never overlays the input value (making it unreadable)

---

Frankly, I would suggest you to simply leave the spans NEXT-TO the INPUTS, just remove the inputs borders. ***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e01azjoc/2/)***